# Menu buttons work, Soft buttons not working. Same Code basically

Tags: java, android, button, menu

Title says it all, Im new to SQL and trying to change the selection the user makes but placing buttons in the screen and not use the MENU button. Seems like the buttons aren't instantiated but the code looks right to me...what am i missing??

```
package com.example.worldcountriesbooks;

import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 
   private TextView newEt;




   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);
      Button a = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editbutton);
       Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deletebutton);
      a.setOnClickListener(this);
      b.setOnClickListener(this); //Set them up right here...

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
       newEt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.newText);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
         int newIndex = result.getColumnIndex("newb");


         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));
         newEt.setText(result.getString(newIndex));


         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }


   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("newb", newEt.getText());

            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }
   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }

public void onClick(View arg0) {
     switch (arg0.getId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("newb", newEt.getText());

                startActivity(addEditContact); 
                break;

             case R.id.deleteItem:
                deleteContact();
                break;//finish them up here and they do nothing...

    }
    }
}
```

Now the menu buttons work great so not sure whats up...Thanks for looking

Comment: "Seems almost like" - not very descriptive or helpful.

Comment: You should post your LogCat stack trace.

Comment: THis is basically the whole logcat..nothing happens when i press the buttons. 
12-24 18:41:52.088: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24522): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 18:41:52.088: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24522): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 18:41:52.088: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24522): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 18:41:52.088: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24522): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 18:41:52.088: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24522): endBatchEdion inactive InputConnection

Comment: Is your app actually crashing or is it a logic issue? If it is crashing, copy the whole red portion of the logcat and *edit* your question to include it.

Comment: Not crashing, just acts like i've inserted buttons with no logic behind them. From what i know...all the logic is right here in the code...thought it might have to do with the menu buttons being nearly identical but when their logic is removed none of them work..(Obviously the menu buttons shouldnt)

Comment: Post your code, xml, logcat, all the stuffs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu buttons work great because the switch statement for it is proper.

Your onClick is not working properly however. This is because The cases are for **different** ids than what the buttons provide. You want `R.id.editbutton` and `R.id.deletebutton` instead.

Your method should look like:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
     switch (arg0.getId())
      {
         case R.id.editbutton: //updated
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("newb", newEt.getText());

                startActivity(addEditContact); 
                break;

             case R.id.deletebutton: //updated
                deleteContact();
                break;

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Dead on. Dumb of me. Thanks gents.  The ids in the onclick were incorrect